# Why is convert_variables_to_constants() deprecated in TF2?

Tags: c, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

As the title says, why is convert_variables_to_constants() deprecated in tensorflow 2? What's the easy replacement to get a saveable model to load into a downstream stand-alone application for inference (in my case, using the C API).

Answer (score 0):

In TF 2.x there is no `tf.Session()`, which is a necessary component to build frozen models in TF 1.x, anymore in TF 2.0.

According to [TensorFlow 2.0.0 release description](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.0.0) "Removed the freeze_graph command-line tool; SavedModel should be used in place of frozen graphs." So, you would be expected to use `SavedModel` only.

However, if you still need frozen graphs you

```py
# Save model to SavedModel format
tf.saved_model.save(model, "./models/simple_model")

# Convert Keras model to ConcreteFunction
full_model = tf.function(lambda x: model(x))
full_model = full_model.get_concrete_function(
    x=tf.TensorSpec(model.inputs[0].shape, model.inputs[0].dtype))

# Get frozen ConcreteFunction
frozen_func = convert_variables_to_constants_v2(full_model)
frozen_func.graph.as_graph_def()

layers = [op.name for op in frozen_func.graph.get_operations()]
```

And then save it as a frozen graph.

> Note: You would now be expected to load this frozen graph with TF 1.x
> functions,

```py
tf.io.write_graph(graph_or_graph_def=frozen_func.graph,
                  logdir="./frozen_models",
                  name="simple_frozen_graph.pb",
                  as_text=False)
```

Then to load this model (**TF 1.x** code) you would do-

```py
with tf.io.gfile.GFile("./frozen_models/simple_frozen_graph.pb", "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    loaded = graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
```

The latency reduced by `freeze_graph` may be quite important for an application and full-precision weights being stored in `SavedModel` could be a problem. But there are simple ways to get past this too, which is outside the scope of this question.